# $gte and $lte in mongoose with multiple condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Am I using `$gte` and `$lte` wrongly with other condition? I got empty array, but when I do just `user_email:req.bodu.user_email` I'm able to get all the data.

```
function firstDayOfMonth() {
  var d = new Date(Date.apply(null, arguments));
  d.setDate(1);
  return d.toISOString();
}

function tomorrowDate() {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)
  return d.toISOString();
}

Users.find({
    "user_email": req.body.user_email,
    "createdAt": {
      "$gte": firstDayOfMonth(),
      "$lte": tomorrowDate()
    }
  },
  function(err, response) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log(response)
      res.json(response);
    }
  });
```

Comment: what is your `firstDayOfMonth` value since your `Date.now()` value is timestamp not date format?

Comment: @abdul, toISOString?

Comment: It's up to you, give same format in both condition and it will work

Comment: Can you show your both functions result ?

Comment: `2016-10-01T06:28:37.000Z`

`2016-10-10T06:28:37.146Z`

Comment: Are you sure that the docs exist in that range can you give one single doc in your collection which comes under this range

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It should work

I just tested with these docs

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f9cc3dc4ac279a7c539d0f"),
    "TechActivityId" : 0,
    "LicenseId" : 0,
    "created" : "2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "StateofActivity" : "State of Activity",
    "TechGId" : "123121134"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f9e674c4ac279a7c539d10"),
    "TechActivityId" : 0,
    "LicenseId" : 0,
    "created" : "2016-10-10T06:28:37.146Z",
    "StateofActivity" : "State of Activity",
    "TechGId" : "1231234"
}

db.getCollection('hola').find({"created":{"$gte":"2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","$lte":"2016-10-10T06:28:37.146Z"}})
```

And I am getting both documents

Comment: I got a typo hahaha

Comment: just wanted to point out, if you wanted to get a date within the range of two dates, you can do $gte and $lt.